# React losing session if refresh browser

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm keeping my user session in a `redux` state.

I have a login reducer with the initialState below

```
const initialState = {
    logged: false,
    user: null,
}
```

After login, I set the logged to true and the user details.

Then, I have a Navigation folder using `react-router-dom` to manage my navigation with a `PrivateRoute` function to validate if user is logged.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...options }) => {
  const login = useSelector((state) => state.login);
    console.log(login);
  const finalComponent = login.logged ? component : Login;

  return <Route {...options} component={finalComponent} />;
};

const Navigation = () => {
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/checkRegister" component={CheckRegister} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default Navigation;
```

Everything works just fine if I open the application login and start to navigate. However, if I refresh the browser or, after login, change the browser from `localhost:3000/` to `localhost:3000/checkRegister` it kills the state and return to the login page because the state `login.logged` is back to the initial value which is `false`.

Comment: If you're using redux everytime you refresh the store the app will reset the state to its default value, take a look at this library if you want to persist the state: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist if you don't want a library you will have to build custom logic that triggers the request to authenticate before rendering the page in order to update the state with the current user before the page has loaded.

Comment: You can try the react-redux-session API. Its very simple to use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-session

Comment: @jean182 Thank you. If you want post it as answer, I will accept. Here is a good example of what you just explained: https://dev.to/bhatvikrant/redux-persist-v6-in-detail-react-10nh

Comment: Thanks I added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux is a client based library, so like react if you perform a refresh the state will be set to the initial state.

You can always use a library like redux persist to persist the state in multiple ways, even if the tab is refreshed: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

As a sidenote as I mention in the comment, you can actually re arrange your code in order to make some side effects before rendering content if you want to avoid using an external library.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options

1. You could use redux-persist as already mentioned by other users.
2. Save your user object in local storage after login. Now when you initialize user state check if you have some value saved in local storage then get that and assign else set it to null.